# How to fix 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused' on creating new database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-artisan

On starting my dockercontainer, I need to create a new db.

Since Laravel doesn't offer a command to create a new database I made my own artisan command ([How to create a mysql db with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832166/how-to-create-a-mysql-db-with-laravel#answer-47316035)).

My Custom command:

```
php artisan make:database newdb
```

When I execute this command, I get the Error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Why do I get this Error? I got this Error in the past when I tried accessing a database which wasn't created yet but now that I am creating a new db I just don't get, why It throws this Error.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you verify the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2972644/369143)?

Comment: it looks like a firewall issue to me.

Comment: @BramVerstraten I am unable to change any firewall settings because it's managed by my employer and my boss as well as my project manager are on vacation. Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: Are you using Fiddler by any chance?

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: What did you put in your .env file for the DB_* settings?

Comment: ```DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret```

Comment: you need to change the DB_username and DB_Password with correct credentials
then run php artisan config:clear

Comment: If you are using Docker on Mac, set `DB_HOST` to `docker.for.mac.host.internal`

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Comment: In that case you should use `docker.for.win.host.internal`